# Visual Studio 2010 - VS1716 - Generate Sequence Diagram

Tags: c#, web, visual-studio-2010, sequence-diagram

I'm working in an ASP.Net C# web application and tried to generate a sequence diagram.  Got an odd error, VS1716:

Cannot generate a sequence diagram due to the following possible reasons:
A method is not selected.
The solution or project is not open
The project type is not supported.
The VS debugger is running.

I'm using VS2010 Ultimate with SP1 and all released updates.  Any ideas what may be causing this?  Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Have you checked the things in the error message? It's pretty clear?

Comment: Yes.  That's why I'm posting.